# Which jobs pay higher and have greater number of open positions; and is such that it requires skills learn-able in short duration for a beginner?

Tags: job-search, skills

I thought to find jobs which pay higher and has greater number of open positions, and is such that it requires skill learn-able in short duration (~ 6 months; at the rate of 21 hours per week) for a beginner. Are there any such jobs? If there are such jobs, which courses/books/certifications do you suggest to get those skills?

Any other suggestions are most welcome. Thank you.

Comment: You are asking for a pipe dream that somehow pays well, has tons of unfilled positions but also is easy to learn. Pick two at most.

Comment: Hi; I don't want it to be too easy to learn. For example, I meant something as this: https://www.coursera.org/promo/googlecloud-promotion-2024

Comment: "Cloud adoption continues to accelerate in the new AI era, IT leaders are looking to attract and retain professionals with cloud and AI skills to match the growth. " - Google Cloud Team

Comment: @Sensebe "it requires skill learn-able in short duration (~ 6 months; at the rate of 21 hours per week)" If something like this can be learnt in 3 months full time equivalent, _lots_ of people will be doing it.

Comment: @Sensebe "Kebab two for one with valid coupon." - Seneka after night of drinking, probably..  Stop listening to slogans and hoping for an easy quick wins, instead put the heavy lifting in. Even in "new fields" like ai (it's far from new but lets ignore that) you have people who have previous relateable experience AND then the months of AI. They are better candidate than you are, and will make more money.

Comment: You have too much academic skill and not enough real-life work experience. Start with a moderately paying job learn hand on work skills (which no college teaches unfortunately) and work your way up. There is reason why compensation is a lot dependent on "experience".

Comment: This question is highly dependent on location. High pay is also highly dependent on location of the job. Move to a place that has high paying jobs and you are more likely to get a high paying job.

Comment: @PhilipKendall: Unless the job has serious drawbacks that drive most competitors away. Unavoidable but highly unpleasant/dangerous working conditions would be the obvious example. The question is whether the OP is willing to do the work of finding and tolerating these. Long-distance trucking can pay well if you don't mind not having a life, damaging your health, and so on. And these are precisely the careers folks employers will most want to replace with automation when that becomes possible. And in some sense they're dead end careers. But if that's what you want...

Answer (score 8):

Dangerous jobs or remote jobs (physically remote locations) such as deep sea rigs or some forestry positions offer. They're very highly paid and need minimal initial skills.

Comment: Now with a reduced amount of limb loss... assuming its a rig that doesn't sling chain anymore.

Comment: I got one statistics book that compared life expectancy in various positions. "Being on death row in Texas" apparently had five years life expectance, "Being a drugs dealer in Detroit" had four, but they suspected the food in jail in Texas was better than many drugs dealers could afford. Forestry (tree feller) and deep sea fishing seem to be quite bad, but not quite as bad.

Comment: Knowing people who have been in Texas prisons, I highly doubt that the food in Texas prisons is better than what drug dealers could afford. Meals in prison were often some mystery meat in a sandwich. Drug dealers can go to a fast-food place. The drug dealer life expectancy is more connected to overdoses and "lead poisoning".

Comment: @DavidR I would have thought drug overdoses apply to drug users rather than drug dealers. 'Lead poisoning makes perfect sense though

Answer (score -4):

I have found below courses which seem to allow beginner to "Prepare for an entry-level job as a data scientist." in 5 months at 10 hours a week.

Data Science Professional Certificate:[^1](https://www.ibm.com/training/badge/data-science-professional-certificate) "The badge earner is ready for a career in data science with demonstrated ability to solve for real-world problems." Course level: Beginner

---